# Javascript structure: Var out of scope. Namespacing

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I'm working on structuring my Javascript code better, and I'm trying to utilise namespacing a lot more. I'm using [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to help guide me to cleaner code.
If I run this through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/):

```
'use strict';
var app = {
    start : function(){
        var x = 1;
        x += 1;
    },

    restart : function(){
        app.start();
    }
};
```

It tells me that `app` is out of scope.

I really like writing `app.start();` instead of `this.start();` since including what a function relates to often is a lot more expressive.

Does JSLint know something that I don't, about variable scope? I know my code works, but is it sloppy in some way? And how ought I do it, if not like this :)?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be happier running it through jshint.com

Comment: @charlietfl Ah, cool! That's a very detailed report it gives you, great tool. I'm still worried about what potential wisdom JSLint could have, that I don't know about though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this warning if you declare your variable first.

```
'use strict';
var app;

app = {
    start : function(){
        var x = 1;
        x += 1;
    },

    restart : function(){
        app.start();
    }
};
```

Comment: What is JSLint trying to say though?
I don't see a functional difference between declaring a variable first and assigning it something, as opposed declaring it and assigning to it :)?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't like if you declare a variable and use it from within the declaration. Doesn't mean it's invalid JS, just that it CAN lead to errors in some cases.

Comment: Like which cases? :)

Comment: https://jslinterrors.com/a-used-out-of-scope
Human errors due to misunderstanding what's actually happening in the code. It doesn't apply to your case. You shouldn't take lint warnings as "bad, need to change" but more like "hey, look at this, are you sure you're doing what you think you're doing"